# Powershell and Powershell Core differences in System.IO.Compression.GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have this code Powershell code:

```
$memory = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$gzip = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GZipStream($memory, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)
$file = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead("c:\test.txt")
$file.CopyTo($gzip)
$file.Close()
$gzip.Close()
Write-Host $memory.ToArray()
# base64 encode the gzipped content
$result = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($memory.ToArray())
Write-Host $result
```

It reads file, gzip content and make base64 encoding.

I run this code using PowerShell 5.1.18362.145 and using PowerShell Core 6.1.5 and get different results. 
Problem is that I am trying to use result that I get in 5.1.18362.145 further in other application, and it doesn't work. However PowerShell Core 6.1.5 result works properly.

I think that there is some difference in PowerShell Core 6.1.5 and PowerShell 5.1.18362.145 and it causes my issue.

Is there any way to force both PowerShell versions to works with same libraries and return the same result? 
Could code somehow be rewritten, but do the same and return same result by both versions?

Comment: Try inserting a `$gzip.Flush()` before `$gzip.Close()`; I'm pretty sure explicitly flushing the stream is necessary in both Core and Framework for this code to be correct, but they may be using different buffering conventions that just happen to make this work under Framework but not Core.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for suggestion, I tried to do it, but nothing changed.

Comment: I wonder if it is compressing with a different algorithm? from [System.Io.Compression.GZipStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netcore-3.0#remarks), it indicates that with .NET 4.5 they changed the default compression algorithm to zlib. The real question is that even though the output is different, does it matter? i.e. ultimately do they decompress the same?

Comment: @HAL9256 In my case it matters, I use output as license key in Sitecore. And for one case(6+) it works, for other it doesn't